# ASP.NET MVC format of posted field information not returning

Tags: asp.net-mvc, forms

I have a form built using ASP.NET MVC and the form data is being shown with controls like so:

```
      <%: Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.thisJob.postcodeto)%>
      <%: Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.thisJob.postcodeto)%>
```

So far so good. However I have just written some backend processing of the submitted information to remove training spaces: 
ie " postcode" becomes "postcode".

These changes are written to the returned ViewModel. I want this change to appear when the form reloads with relevant error messages.

When I debug and check the ViewModel the spaces have been removed however when the page returns the original un-cleaned input is there. It seems that the display controls read the information from the ModelState rather than the object passed into the View.

I have tried finding the values in the ModelState and updating them with the cleaned values but [set] seems to be disallowed.

What I am trying to do seems pretty standard.

Any pointers / ideas / bits of code will be gratefully received.

Answer (score 2):

This is a known behaviour because the `ModelState` contains all the errors and values that need to go back. You can use `ModelState.Clear()` and then add your own errors, or just try modifying relevant ModelState values.

### (Update)

Really, in the heart of MVC, we are not supposed to make modifications to the Model while we are sending it back to the form - only when saving back to database.

I do not think it is wise to trim the spaces since you end up loosing the benefits of default model binder and then having to work around it. So you are trying to solve a problem - which I believe - does not exist.

Comment: Hi Aliostad. I have tried something like this without success.                                          ValueProviderResult r = new ValueProviderResult();
                r.RawValue = "HELLO";                

                ModelState["thisJob_postcodeto"].Value = r;